# MOS device sizes

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, nmos, pmos

[image]

Hello guys! I just want to ask what's the difference between the actual W/L and the W/L shown at the image below? I'm kind of confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that plain "W/L" is given in multiples of the **scale factor**. The heading for the table says that the scale factor is 50 nm, so multiply the plain W/L by the scale factor and you get the actual W/L in meters.

This looks like part of a "scalable" design philosophy, which is intended to create designs that can be easily scaled to different MOSFET design rules by just changing the scale factor. It was also called **lambda-based** design, where lambda was the scale factor.